# Conditionally set a relational operator in Python

Tags: python

I wish to create a function which filters a data set, and I wish to pass into that function the logic of whether to search `<`, `>` or `==`.

Is there a preferred method for this in Python, or do I need to create 3 different unique code bases for each using `elif` for example

```
if rel_operator == "gt":
    print("GT OPERATION")
elif rel_operator == "lt":
    print("LT OPERATION")
elif rel_operator == "eq":
    print("EQ OPERATION")
```

Comment: you can use `operator.lt, operator.le, operator.ne`

Comment: @aws_apprentice I believe that should be an answer

Comment: sure one second I will update, I am usually hesitant to post short concise things such as this as an answer. well looks like someone beat me to it, haha

Comment: Please post your answer @aws_apprentice, I shall certainly accept yours if posted.

Comment: @SingleEntity Python supports higher-order functions, so generally, you can always pass a function. Even if the `operator` module doesn't provide what you need, you can always do something like `def my_binary_operator(a,b): return a*b + a/b` and then refer to the operations by `my_binary_operator`. Remember, *functions work just like any other object*.

Comment: @SingleEntity also, you can think of any operator as merely syntactic sugar for some "dunder" method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python's built-in `operator` module:

```
< corresponds to operator.lt

> corresponds to operator.gt 
# I was hasty in writing le in my comment

== corresponds to operator.eq
```

Following @Nick A comment you can do this:

```
d = {'gt': operator.gt.__doc__,
'lt':operator.lt.__doc__,
'eq':operator.eq.__doc__}

rel_operator = 'gt'
d.get(rel_operator)

'gt(a, b) -- Same as a>b.'
```

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the comments and the other answer you can use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module which wraps the comparison operators as callables.

In case you want to pass in a string you could simply get the appropriate callable with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
import operator

rel_operator = "gt"  # for example
real_rel_operator = getattr(operator, rel_operator)
```

and then call the `real_rel_operator` with the values as arguments. That works because your strings are already what the functions are called. No need to create a dictionary in this case.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by aws_apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307104/conditionally-set-a-relational-operator-in-python#comment79576054_46307104), pass your function

```
operator.gt, operator.lt, operator.eq
```

and you can use them as your comparators.

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html

Comment: Relational operators as functions, I've never heard of this, thanks.  You were so fast in answering, I have to wait 10 minutes to accept your answer! :)

Comment: maybe provide how this would relate to the code? otherwise I would think that you just went ahead and copy pasted a comment...

Comment: Even better, create a dictionary mapping the names (`"gt"` etc.) to these operators to remove the if statements